# Is there a way to drag and drop program shortcuts to the desktop in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: shortcuts, .desktop, customization, 19.04

There are several posts for this already but they are all outdated and I want to know if it can be done more simply now.

Is there a way to open the dash menu and add a program to the desktop by right mouse clicking or something? Or do  I still need to go to `use/share/applications` then copy and paste to the desktop and then make it an executable?

Recap, I know this has been asked before but is there a better way now?

Comment: Not likely, because now desktop icons are supported by an experimental extension. Possibly, you can't even drag files from nautilus to the desktop now.

Comment: Dragging and dropping to the desktop from `usr/share/applications` doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @vanadium Why would they remove a feature like that?

Comment: @NiallMitch14 Why would they remove a feature like that?

Comment: No clue. I was disappointed seeing that my previous shortcuts didn't work when I upgraded

Comment: It is now different technology. Perhaps a matter of time before the developpers of the extension implement the connection with the file manager.

Comment: @vanadium Ok, would you mind writing an answer to this post simply saying there is no other way at the moment, I keep getting auto flagged because people keep not writing answers.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable here to write your own answer, and accept it, if further research and information brought you to a valid answer. So please go ahead.

Comment: @vanadium "if further research and information brought you to a valid answer" you answered it though, it's only right you get the points.

Comment: In the mean time, I did some more testing. I normally do not work with desktop icons/launchers, so that is why I initially hesitated to answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 19.04, like in previous Ubuntu versions, it is not possible to drag applications from the dash or the application menu to the desktop.

Desktop files from Ubuntu 19.04 onwards are handled by a Gnome Shell extension, and not anymore by files. You can still copy or create .desktop files on the desktop as before. The right-click menu has an option "allow launching" to turn that .desktop file into a launcher.