# Files (Nautilus) in 19.10 - drag-n-drop on desktop doesn't work

Tags: nautilus, 19.10, desktop-icons, drag-and-drop

If I insert a flash drive and try to drag any files onto desktop - nothing happens.

Or from any other folder.

Drag 'n copy only works if you open desktop in nautilus ("show desktop in files").

I already ran the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences use-experimental-views false
```

It didn't help. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Since Ubuntu 19.04, Nautilus [doesn't handle desktop icon management](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158), rather it is handled by a GNOME Shell Extension called '*Desktop Icons*' (package name: [`gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons)). The extension doesn't support the drag-and-drop feature yet.

However, you can replace Nautilus with Nemo as your file manager and get the traditional desktop icon management back. Follow this Q&A to replace Nautilus by Nemo: [Make nemo the default file browser](https://askubuntu.com/q/260244/480481).

You should disable/remove the Desktop Icons extension to avoid any potential incompatibility. You may also have to add Nemo manually to the list of (auto-) startup programs.

Answer (score 3):

Support of icons on the desktop in Ubuntu 19.10 is still limited for [reasons outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135074/is-there-a-way-to-drag-and-drop-program-shortcuts-to-the-desktop-in-ubuntu-19-04/1135729#1135729). Thus, you currently cannot (yet) drag and drop files from Nautilus to the desktop. For the moment, your workarounds are:

- Copying using the keyboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then click on desktop and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).
- (As you mentionned:) You can drag files in Nautilus to the Desktop folder in your home directory. These files will appear on the desktop.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`c` and `Ctrl`+`v` doesn't work for me. Nothing happens when I press `Ctrl`+`v`. But it does work when I select `paste` from the right click menu. Help. Also, is HTML not supported in comments?

Comment: I'm running 20.10 and I still can't drag a file out of trash back to the desktop. This is hilarious!

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to uninstall the "Desktop Icons" extension and install this one:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/?c=80141

[image]

I lightly tested it, and for now drag and drop works as supposed to do and moving icons in different screens also.

Additionally, it's *much* more configurable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, Nautilus has to be uninstalled after Nemo installation and it needs an extra start application command: nemo-desktop. This is to avoid the desktop getting filled by duplicated dragged icons etc if Nautilus is still present. Then it needs gnome-shell-extension-dekstop-icons to be installed.

Comment: donwgrade to nautilus 3.26 plus desktop extension (NG) does it.